# How to pass access token in url header of swagger ui using asp.net web api?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, swagger, access-token, swagger-ui

I have a swagger API in asp.net. I am using token based authentication in my project. I get the token in response by a post request in tokenendpointpath 
[/token].Now i need to pass that token automatically with every request curl Authorization header. I tried in many ways but its not working.I don't want the user to every time input that token when request. Please kindly help me to get rid of this issue.

//request for token

[image]

//request for resource

[image]

//Swagger.config class

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{

    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.DocumentFilter<AuthTokenOperation>();
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "API");
                    c.PrettyPrint();
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {

                    c.DocumentTitle("MY API");

                });
    }
}
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to web api .net framework

```
.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
    c.DocumentFilter<AuthTokenOperation>();
    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "API");
    c.PrettyPrint();

     c.ApiKey("apiKey")
        .Description("API Key for accessing secure APIs")
        .Name("Api-Key")
        .In("header");                  
})
```

Comment: Its not working I am using asp.net web api not asp.net core .Here is my Swagger.config file i got from swashbuckle nuget package.I added my swagger.config class in post.I am stuck here 3 days.No idea how to pass that token